# Javascript split with regular expression return empty values

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Hi I have to split a string in two parts, the first one is always a char the second one is a number.
i.e.
a12
c4

I try to use this expression:

```js
var myString = 'a12';
var mySplits = myString.split(/^([a-zA-Z]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})$/); 
console.log(mySplits);
```

the array expected is:

```
["a", "12"]
```

the result instead is:

```
["", "a", "12", ""]
```

I don't understand the reason why the result array has an empty value at start and at end.

Any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

the solution proposed works but we can use a more elegant way.

**ES18**

With ES18 we could use the group capturing name

```js
var myString = 'a12';
var matches = 
/^(?<letter>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(?<number>[0-9]{1,2})$/.exec(myString).concat();

console.log(matches.groups.letter);
console.log(matches.groups.number);
```

**ES10**

ES10 added the method .matchAll() that returns an Iterator, so if the need is not capture a single value but capture globally this method can be useful.

```js
var myString = 'a12 b12 ';
for (const match of myString.matchAll(/(?<letter>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(?<number>[0-9]{1,2})/g)) {
  console.log(match.groups.letter);
  console.log(match.groups.number);
}
```

Comment: That is because you're using `split` and your entire regex is matching input. Why not use match instead with `^([a-zA-Z]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myString = 'a12';
var list = /^([a-zA-Z]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})$/.exec(myString).concat();
list.shift();    // remove the first element
console.log(list); //This is the list that you want
```